# How to delete the Token from backend in Django

Tags: python, reactjs, django, django-rest-auth

I'm using django rest-auth along with the django rest api. I can logout the user by calling rest-auth/logout in the browsable api and it will delete the token from the Database. In the browsable api, I don't have to send the Token along with the logout url. I called the same url rest-auth/logout from a React js front end and it gives the response as  'successfully logged out' but Token remains in the database. How can I remove the Token by calling the url from the front end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must send a `DELETE` request and use this code:

```
class LogoutView(APIView):
""" Logout User """

@staticmethod
def delete(request, *args, **kwargs):
    request.user.auth_token.delete()
    data = {
        "message": "You have successfully logged out.",
    }
    return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: I tried this code. It deletes the token from the database. But the user stays in the browsable api and I can call authentication required views even after I deletes the Token

Comment: User default logout request from django to take care of user session

Comment: @NavanjaneVidunuwanKindelpiti how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Hi i would use a differente approach.

1. Each login, delete and create a new token
2. Each logout call `logout` method

```py
from django.contrib import auth

class LoginView(APIView):
""" Login User """

    @staticmethod
    def post(request, *args, **kwargs):
        # get username and password
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            Token.objects.filter(user=user).delete()
            token = Token.objects.create(user=user)
            auth.login(request, user)
            # redirect to whatever with token key
        # error return here
 
class LogoutView(APIView):
""" Logout User """

    @staticmethod
    def delete(request, *args, **kwargs):
        auth.logout(request)
        data = {
            "message": "You have successfully logged out.",
        }
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: This wouldn't work well in a multi-device setting where the API is used e.g. on a person's phone and iPad to login to an app. If you logged in on one device, you wouldn't be authenticated on another. Usually, this is not desired behaviour.